# PDO not recognising NOT EXISTS clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running a query via PDO. The query runs fine when I run it directly in phpMyAdmin console, but returns incorrectly when run via PDO. It returns rows as though the NOT EXISTS clause were not there. My query is effectively like this:

```
SELECT ul.session, CONCAT(u.firstname,' ', u.lastname) AS owner, ...
  FROM usagelog ul 
 INNER JOIN companies c ON ul.company=c.companyid
 INNER JOIN users u ON ul.user=u.userid
 WHERE (ul.company=:compid OR 0=:compid)
   AND ul.created BETWEEN :start AND :end
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT ss.session FROM seshstatechangelog ss WHERE ss.session=ul.session AND ss.stateto != :state) 
 ORDER BY ul.created
```

I have tried with both `?` style binding of variables and `:` as you see here.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Give `AND (ul.created BETWEEN :start AND :end)` and try.

Comment: @nana partykar It worked, thankyou - but why did it need the brackets?

Comment: I wrote it as my answer. @AntG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ul.session, CONCAT(u.firstname,' ', u.lastname) AS owner, ...
  FROM usagelog ul 
 INNER JOIN companies c ON ul.company=c.companyid
 INNER JOIN users u ON ul.user=u.userid
 WHERE (ul.company=:compid OR 0=:compid)
   AND (ul.created BETWEEN :start AND :end)
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT ss.session FROM seshstatechangelog ss WHERE ss.session=ul.session AND ss.stateto != :state) 
 ORDER BY ul.created
```

Give, `AND (ul.created BETWEEN :start AND :end)`. When, there are many condition. Try to enclose it with using `(` and `)`. It will be easy for readability. May be  `AND :end` and `AND NOT EXISTS` is taken as one condition.

Use `parenthesis()` to get a result from `NOT EXISTS`, because you want one or the other, then you use AND to get the `created date` range and finally an AND to join the results from `company id`.